# Excluding configuration in test classes from @ComponentScan

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, junit, spring-java-config

I've been running into `@ComponentScan` issues with `@Configuration` classes for tests -- namely, the `@ComponentScan` is pulling in unintended `@Configuration` during integration tests.

For example, say you've got some global config in `src/main/java` which pulls in components within `com.example.service`, `com.example.config.GlobalConfiguration`:

```
package com.example.config;
...
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = ServiceA.class)
public class GlobalConfiguration {
    ...
}
```

It's intended to pull in two services, `com.example.services.ServiceA` and `com.example.services.ServiceB`, annotated with `@Component` and `@Profile("!test")` (omitted for brevity).

Then in src/test/java, `com.example.services.ServiceATest`:

```
package com.example.services;
...
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = ServiceATest.ServiceATestConfiguration.class)
public class ServiceATest {
    ...
    @Configuration
    public static class ServiceATestConfiguration {
         @Bean
         public ServiceA serviceA() {
             return ServiceA(somemocking...);
         }
    }
}
```

And also `com.example.ServiceBIntegrationTest`, which needs to pull in `GlobalConfiguration.class` in order to be an integration test, but still avoids pulling in dangerous implementations with `@ActiveProfiles("test")`:

```
package com.example.services;
...
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {GlobalConfiguration.class, ServiceBIntegrationTest.ServiceBIntegrationTestConfiguration.class})
public class ServiceBIntegrationTest {
    ...
    @Configuration
    public static class ServiceBIntegrationTestConfiguration {
         @Bean
         public ServiceB serviceB() {
             return ServiceB(somemocking...);
         }
    }
}
```

The obvious intention of the `ServiceBIntegrationTest` is to pull in the complete `src/main/java` application configuration via `GlobalConfiguration`, exclude dangerous components via `@ActiveProfiles("test")` and replace those excluded components with its own implementations. However, during tests the namespace of `src/main/java` and `src/test/java` are combined, so `GlobalConfiguration`'s  `@ComponentScan` finds more in the classpath than it normally would -- namely, the `ServiceA` bean defined in `ServiceA.ServiceATestConfiguration`. That could easily lead to conflicts and unintended results.

Now, you could do something on `GlobalConfiguration` like `@ComponentScan(..., excludeFilters= @ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.REGEX, pattern = "\\.*(T|t)est\\.*"))`, but that has issues of its own. Relying on naming conventions is pretty brittle; still, even if you backed out a `@TestConfiguration` annotation and used `FilterType.ANNOTATION`, you'd effectively be making your `src/main/java` aware of your `src/test/java`, which it shouldn't be, IMO (see **note** below).

As it stands, I've solved my problem by using an additional profile. On `ServiceA`, I add a unique profile name -- so that its profile annotation becomes something like `@ActiveProfiles("test,serviceatest")`. Then, on `ServiceATest.ServiceATestConfiguration` I add the annotation `@Profile("serviceatest")`. This effectively limits the scope of `ServiceATestConfiguration` with relatively little overhead, but it seems like either:

a) I am using `@ComponentScan` incorrectly, or

b) There should be a much cleaner pattern for handling this problem

Which is it?

---

**note**: yes, the app is test-aware because it's using `@Profile("!test")`, but I'd argue making the application slightly test-aware to defend against improper resource usage and making it test-aware to ensure  correctness of tests are very different things.

Answer (score 3):

I see you are trying to fake Spring beans during integration test. If you combine `@Profile` and `@ActiveProfiles` annotation with `@Primary` annotation, most of your headaches should go away and you shouldn't need to mark production beans with `@Profile("!test")`.

I wrote a [blog post on the topic](https://lkrnac.net/blog/2015/12/mock-spring-bean-v2/) with [Github examples](https://github.com/lkrnac/blog-2015-11-mock-spring-bean-v2).

Reaction on comment:

By package structure. Component scan scans all packages within current package and sub-packages. IF you don't want to scan beans, just amend your package structure the way that bean wouldn't be under your component scan umbrella.

Spring doesn't differentiate packages from `src/test/java` or `src/main/java`. Trying to exclude production beans with `@Profile("!test")` is design smell. You should avoid it. I would suggest to give a chance to approach from mentioned blog.

Notice that when you override the bean with @Primary annotation, you may need to use `@DirtiesContext` annotation to have clean sheet for other tests.

Comment: Yeah, there are some advantages to that pattern, but that's not what my question is about. I'm asking how to best limit the scope of configuration within a component-scanned package.

Comment: Changing the packaging would be in conflict with package local scoping, which is obviously important for testing. This is unsatisfactory.